# reload and render combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

I work with extjs 3.4

I have a problem when I try to assign  defaut value in combobox

this is my code :

```
<form:combobox property="from_tr"
                        displayField="fullname" valueField="id"
                        allowBlank="true" editable="true" forceSelection="true"
                        pageSize="10" hideTrigger="true" width="400"
                        fields="address" lang="<%=lang%>"
                        tpl='<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item"><b>{fullname}</b><br>{address}</div></tpl>'
                        dataStore="com.testStore" autoLoad="false" />
```

in  onready function I make this code :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

var idAdr='AB-20';

 var store = from_tr_myPage.getStore();
    store.load({
   callback: function() {
      from_tr_myPage.setValue(idAdr);
   }
});

    });
```

but after test I have this value **AB-20** in combobox

in the combobox I want to show the **fullname**

I try without success to render and reload the combobox

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you try to html with extjs component, it will unnecessary 
complex. Why don't you use the combobox component which sencha is providing.

I suggest to use inbuilt component as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var index = store.find("id", idAdr);
var recordSelected = store.getAt(index);
from_tr_myPage.setValue(recordSelected.get('fullname'));
```

Hope this helps.